# How do you apply patches on a web project at production server?

Tags: version-control, patch

We recently had a project where we released beta of a big web app on our client's server. Our client requested us to do bug fixes as they come, and we tried to do it same way. Normally while building an app on our prototype server is way easier, as I just have to issue simple 'svn up' command which takes a second.

But on production environment, we do not have any version control tool available. Is it possible to automate the patching work, so that we need not to login to ftp and upload each a every file one by one?

Its very difficult to work this way. As I'm having this problem, its for sure that some of you have already solved the problem. Please share your solutions.

Looking forward to your replies... Thanks a lot for reading guys.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the tools available on the server, you could either do a `svn diff -r x:y` where x is the revision you last updated too and y the last revision you want to update to (probably the last revision on your repository) to generate a patch and then apply the patch with the `patch` command.

If `rsync` is available on the production platform, and you can use it (though ssh for instance) you could set up a production ready tree, rsync it on the production server, and when an update comes in, svn update your production tree, and rsync it again.

Answer (score 1):

What is stopping you from installing a Subversion client on the production server?

[EDIT] So someone doesn't allow you to install the software you need on the server. The question is: What is more important? A stable production server or an arbitrary policy? If the someone doesn't listen to arguments, go to your computer, start MS Word and write this letter:

"I hereby refuse to accept any responsibility for the stability of our production system based on the fact that [insert name here] refuses to equip me with the tools to make sure that the production system contains all the necessary files and data after an installation."

Sign this, have your boss sign it and then send a copy to [insert name here]. All of a sudden, any problem that might arise after an installation will be on his turf. Or to put it more clearly: He will be responsible for any mistake you might make.

Now, all you have to do is wait. :)

Comment: We do not have permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the programming environment you use. In Smalltalk and the web application server like [Aida/Web](http://www.aidaweb.si) we can upgrade the live web applications on the fly, without stopping it.

The server is connected to the SCM of choice like Monticello for Squeak Smalltalk or Store for VisualWorks. New versions are then manually or automatically loaded to the server's Smalltalk image.